# ffmpeg output + issues

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to get ffmpeg to work using PHP, in its most basic format, just as a test before i develop my code further.

However i can not get it to work and get no error messages or indications to what is wrong :-(

i am trying:

```
echo exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i /home/xxxxxx/public_html/videos/1746/0765916.avi /home/xxxxxx/public_html/videos/1746/test.mp4");
```

this is creating a 0kb file, but nothing else :-(
i get no error message (or anything else!)

(i have error_reporting turned ON and nothing is displayed in browser or server logs)

if i add the below to get the codecs available:

```
echo exec("ffmpeg -formats");
```

this just outputs "worse."

I do not have access to command line, as i am using a shared hosting server.

I have had the host run the above from command line, and they say it says "codec not found" or words to the effect.

is there any way i can get any error output into my php file so i can see what is happening.

Also how do i go about installing codecs, if this is the problem (the host will install them, but have mentioned they have never installed a codec on a Linux box, so would be grateful if i could point them to any install info too)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

after adding in the code that @stewe suggests, this is the output when trying to convert to mp4

(i can convert to to other formats fine )

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.10-4:0.5.10-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice
Bellard, et al. configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.10-1
--prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static libavutil 49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0 libavcodec 52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1 libavformat 52.31. 0 /
52.31. 0 libavdevice 52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0 libavfilter 0. 4. 0 / 0. 4. 0 libswscale 0. 7. 1 / 0. 7. 1 libpostproc 51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0 built on
Feb 16 2013 10:07:01, gcc: 4.4.5 Input #0, avi, from
'/home/xxxxx/public_html/videos/1746/0765916.avi':
Duration: 00:01:37.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 868 kb/s Stream #0.0:
Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 480x272 [PAR 1:1 DAR 30:17], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25
tbc Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s Output
#0, mp4, to '/home/xxxxx/public_html/videos/1746/test.mp4':
Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 480x272 [PAR 1:1 DAR 30:17],
q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc Stream #0.1: Audio: 0x0000, 48000
Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s Stream mapping: Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 Stream
#0.1 -> #0.1 [mpeg4 @ 0x9fb7880]removing common factors from framerate Unsupported codec for output stream #0.1
```

If anyone can help as to how to fix this issue, as i would ideally like to convert to mp4

Comment: This should give you the full output: `echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -formats 2>&1");`

Comment: @stewe Thanks, it does. it gives a full page of info, including several mentions of .avi and .mp4. However adding shell_exec to my conversion test still does and outputs nothing (apart from writing test.mp4 @ 0kb). should it do?

Comment: did you also append `2>&1` to the conversion command?

Comment: @stewe ahhh no (i didnt know what it did :-))... i have added it now and it give lots of info, followed by "Unsupported codec for output stream #0.1". would this mean i need to install the mp4 codec? (i tried an mpeg conversion and this works!!! :-) )

Comment: i don't know ffmpeg very well, but from reading the error message, i'd guess your hosting provider has to install the codec.

Comment: @stewe Thanks alot, this have been very helpful, i will try installing the mp4 codec and hopefully all will then work!

Comment: Please update your question with the complete output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i have added the output message as requested. any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You get the full output like this:

```
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -formats 2>&1");
```

the `2>&1` part redirects the stderr to stdout, so you also get the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

## Your `ffmpeg` is ancient

FFmpeg development is [very active](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=shortlog), but you're using version SVN-r0.5.10-4:0.5.10-1. This is incredibly old and is unsupported by the FFmpeg project.

I'll bet once you get a recent version it will work as expected. Note that once you upgrade if your new build supports libx264, then it will encode H.264 video for MP4 output. Your current geriatric build is outputting MPEG-4 Part 2 video instead.

### Upgrading options

Note that you can't just "install a codec" and expect FFmpeg to work. Here are some methods to upgrade:

- **[Download a build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)**. Point your script to it. Simple and easy.
- **Compile `ffmpeg`**. [Refer to a step-by-step compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide). Should work on shared servers as long as they provide the proper packages needed to compile (`gcc` and `make` at a minimum).
- **Ask your host to upgrade.** They may or may not know how to do this or they may only provide another ancient build.